# Stop internet service provider website from loading automatically every time I connect to internet for the first time

Tags: internet

I am using a 3g dongle for Internet connection, every time I connect to the Internet the website of my service provider opens up automatically. Is there a way to stop it from happening? I once installed their cross platform user -interface, and couldn't remove it properly or undo the changes it did.

Comment: Does it happen even if you don't use the dongle?

Comment: No it doesn't happen when i connect to Internet using my other dongle which is unlocked version. The one i am having problem with was bought from the service provider itself which is MTS

Comment: Unless you can find a way to edit the files on the dongle, I don't think this is possible. Give me the model number and I'll look it up.

Comment: The manufacturer is ZTE model AC2787, i have an impression that some program is sitting in my OS manipulating the url when ever i connect to Internet and type a web address. Boz no matter what web address you type it automatically changes to the ISP website. It happens only once between every connect and disconnect.

Comment: It sounds like a login page, where it goes to ask for a login, but then realizes you've already done that, so it just goes to the page it would go to after the carrier login. I think this is a bug you can't really fix.

Comment: oh that's sad, it started to show up only after i installed their Linux version interface. May be it was as stupid idea boz the connection was just fine with out it. Anyway thanks for ur help

Comment: You can probably remove it. What the name of the package/program?

Comment: ztemtsapplication, it didn't came as a .deb file, the installation took place by executing a script file.

Comment: Do you have the download link?

Comment: no the install files were in the dongle itself

Comment: Can you edit the script's contents into your question? I might be able to tell where it installed files to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ways to find this software:

Look at the output of `ps -ewfH` -- does anything in there look like the brand name of the dongle or the service provider?

In a terminal, run `grep -Ri <brand-name> /etc/` , where `<brand-name>` is some distinctive part of the brand name of the service provider or dongle. If you get any matches, that might tell you how the script is auto-starting.

If you remember the date when you first installed the software that came with the dongle, you can try to find the files it modified by doing:

```
find / -newermt <1 day before dongle> ! -newermt <1 day after dongle>
```

for instance, if you did the dongle software install on December 21st of last year:

```
find / -newermt "2014-12-20" ! -newermt "2014-12-22"
```

Very slow, but might work:

```
grep -Rli "<distinctive part of url the software takes you to>" /
```

This searches every file on the system for that URL. If you have 1 TB of files, this will take approximately 3-4 hours to complete. You can speed it up by first trying with `/usr /etc /*b* /var /opt` in place of the last `/`, but if the script is hiding in your home directory, that won't catch it.

Extreme measures:

On a different computer (one that you don't mind reformatting), take a full backup of every file. Then, connect the dongle to it and install the software. Now compare the entire machine to the full backup, and see what changed.